# Major Mail Issue - SMTP Local Server Not Working

Tags: email, smtp

My database (MySQL), web server (IIS 8 ) AND SMTP server (IIS 6) are all on the same dedicated server (Windows Server 2012) that I'm honestly renting for a bit of system admin practice. I followed a guide on how to install a local SMTP server then did a "test" email by dropping a txt file including the "To: From: Subject: and Body:" fields in the "Pickup" folder in email route. It sent successfully to my gmail.

Then I tried running this simple php test on my website from the actual server (secure browser):

```
<?php 
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "emailtest@YOURDOMAIN";
    $to = "YOUREMAILADDRESS";
    $subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
    $message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "Test email sent";
?>
```

It returned this error:

```
mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the SMTP server service running?

Comment: Yes it is. I have it set to automatically start in the services manager.

Comment: Can you post your php.ini part corresponding to your SMTP configuration ?
Does your smtp server require an authentification ?

Comment: @lazzio It is setup to allow anonymous access and it is also setup to only allow access from the local machine. 
  
`[mail function]  
; For Win32 only.  
; php.net/smtp  
SMTP = localhost  
; php.net/smtp-port  
smtp_port = 25  
  
; For Win32 only.  
; php.net/sendmail-from  
sendmail_from = donotreply@novitasbloc.com`

Comment: Can you telnet SMTP port at `localhost`?  Do you get SMTP greeting message? `telnet localhost 25`